# Message: unserialize(): Error at offset 1683 of 1718 bytes

Tags: php, serialization, codeigniter-3

As mentioned in the title, I get this error everytime I try to get data from the database.

Actually, this data is from `Sandbox Paypal(IPN MESSAGE),` I want to display it in a table but, I couldn't get this data.

**The data :**

```
mc_gross=255.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&item_number1=&payer_id=Q8XQ4Y9Q53QXW&address_street=1 Main St&payment_date=10:12:23 Apr 27, 2018 PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&mc_shipping=5.00&first_name=firas&mc_fee=7.70&address_country_code=US&address_name=firas jerbi&notify_version=3.9&custom=52e4d14b5f86928ac956f97dd6accc1f22a27273227b19b7c6c08d2af5e4593d8b99c6bbf7b501b31f586eee32bf7df4311cbb37f97e82f0f793701f67347138mcv2LOikNuxtUksoCAUBjOa3kxbtOWtsi+jTUdhf6QsDqooEgR43s3CyddU9gTWtKtNu34HjtGwGkkza89Tn6w==&payer_status=verified&business=firasmerchant@gmail.com&address_country=United States&num_cart_items=1&address_city=San Jose&verify_sign=AR6P4zSMdK8xkhzWMvTgEQtF6rBEAxyx3ttetekDL89SnCf8Bqbiz.IL&payer_email=firasbuyer@gmail.com&mc_shipping1=5.00&txn_id=3GE77135FE112680G&payment_type=instant&last_name=jerbi&address_state=CA&item_name1=Feuillard plastique et acier&receiver_email=firasmerchant@gmail.com&payment_fee=7.70&quantity1=1&receiver_id=4LS2N7RBPEKD2&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=255.00&mc_currency=USD&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=255.00&ipn_track_id=e3f1d75b453a2
```

**ps:** I'm putting the data manually, after the payment is done. I tried every solution in the stackoverflow forum, none of them worked for me, please help!!
And thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

use `parse_str` to parse the given string

```
$string = 'mc_gross=255.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&item_number1=&payer_id=Q8XQ4Y9Q53QXW&address_street=1 Main St&payment_date=10:12:23 Apr 27, 2018 PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&mc_shipping=5.00&first_name=firas&mc_fee=7.70&address_country_code=US&address_name=firas jerbi&notify_version=3.9&custom=52e4d14b5f86928ac956f97dd6accc1f22a27273227b19b7c6c08d2af5e4593d8b99c6bbf7b501b31f586eee32bf7df4311cbb37f97e82f0f793701f67347138mcv2LOikNuxtUksoCAUBjOa3kxbtOWtsi+jTUdhf6QsDqooEgR43s3CyddU9gTWtKtNu34HjtGwGkkza89Tn6w==&payer_status=verified&business=firasmerchant@gmail.com&address_country=United States&num_cart_items=1&address_city=San Jose&verify_sign=AR6P4zSMdK8xkhzWMvTgEQtF6rBEAxyx3ttetekDL89SnCf8Bqbiz.IL&payer_email=firasbuyer@gmail.com&mc_shipping1=5.00&txn_id=3GE77135FE112680G&payment_type=instant&last_name=jerbi&address_state=CA&item_name1=Feuillard plastique et acier&receiver_email=firasmerchant@gmail.com&payment_fee=7.70&quantity1=1&receiver_id=4LS2N7RBPEKD2&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=255.00&mc_currency=USD&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=255.00&ipn_track_id=e3f1d75b453a2';

parse_str($string, $output);
print_r($output);
```

`$output` produces an `array` : see the working example : https://eval.in/999678

pass it in your view :

```
$this->load->view('your_view',$output);
```

In your view (putting some example):

```
<table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>MC Gross</td>
         <td>Protection Eligibility</td>
         <td>Address Status</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $mc_gross;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $protection_eligibility;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $address_status;?></td>
            ...........
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php